# I want to show the results of the stars in different lines as attached using the below function

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I want the stars to be incremented or decremented by row, in other words I want the first line to show 1 star, the second 2 stars, the 3rd 3 stars etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function seethestars() {
        stars = ["*", "**", "***", "****", "*****"];
        for (var i = 0, l = stars.length; i < l; i++) {
            document.getElementById("emptytext2").value = (stars[i] + "");
        }
    }
</script>
<textarea id="emptytext2" name="S2"></textarea></td>

<input id="emptytext3" type="button" value="Click for the stars" onclick ="seethestars()" /><tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this

[image]

Comment: `.value += stars[i] + '\n'`. use `+=` to append, and include a new line,

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is loop backwards through the array. This is not difficult. You just need to start your `for` loop at `stars.length` and go down to `0`, rather than counting up.

You also need to make the `=` into `+=`, to make Javascript append to rather than replace the existing content.

```
function seethestars() {
    stars = ["*", "**", "***", "****", "*****"];
    for (var i = stars.length; i--; ) {
        document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += (stars[i] + "\n");
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/zEswX/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var n=10;
function seethestars() {
   var s;
   document.getElementById("emptytext2").value = "";
   for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      s="";
      for (var j=0; j < i; j++) {
         s+="*";
      }
      document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += s+"\n";
   }
}
```

I have not tried the code, but I believe it should look like something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function

```
<script>
    function DrawStars(LinesNo) {
        for (var j=1;j<LinesNo;j++)  {
           for( var i =0 ;i<j;i++) {
              document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "*";
           }
           document.getElementById("emptytext2").value += "\n";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Watch Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aswinlutchanah/NWUhJ/)**
`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function seethestars() {
        //Stars incrementation
        stars = 5;
        var starsHtml = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= stars; i++) {
            starsHtml += Array(i+1).join("*")+ "\n";
        }
        document.getElementById("emptytext2").value = starsHtml;
    }
    //Stars decrementation
    function seethestarsReverse() {
        stars = 5;
        var starsHtml = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= stars; i++) {
            starsHtml += Array(i+1).join("*")+ "\n";
        }
        var starsHtml = starsHtml.split("").reverse().join("").substring(1);
        document.getElementById("emptytext2").value = starsHtml;
    }
</script>
```

`